# В Visual Studio Community 2022 при запуске андроид эмулятора выводит ошибку

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Пытаюсь запустить андроид эмулятор в VSC 2022, но выводит такую ошибку:

"В ходе развёртывания произошли ошибки. Продолжить?"

[image: ошибка]

Comment: В окне "Вывод" или чет типа такого ошибки подробной нет? Или может в списке ошибок есть что?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , ошибок нигде нету, только это окно ошибки высвечивается и всё